# Lulei Sorascha (song)

Tags: sources-mekorot, song-poetry, music

What are the words and the source of the Shlomo Carlebach song, "Lulei Sorascha (Without Your Torah)"?

I feel that I must have encountered this verse in Tehillim (which I believe is where it comes from), but I was either not thinking about the song whenever I have said this, or else it just didn't stick with me. In any case, I just can't remember or figure out for sure where it is from or what the words are. Surely someone here can help me out. Please?

Edit: [I tried Google and came up with bupkes!](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18395/lulei-sorascha-song#comment44366_18395)

Comment: Google is your friend!

Comment: @Dave I think his problem was that he didn't know how to spell it. (For example, לולי could have been לולא; and שעשועי could have been written in a number of malei/chaser forms; and עניי could have been עני (as in ותרא את עני אבותינו)

Comment: Related: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/

Comment: @msh210 is it really that much of a guessing game when that much detail is included in the question?

Comment: @SethJ, yes, IMO. And that blog post says that that's a bad thing. But you'd have to get one of the other mods, or the crowd of voters-to-close, to close it.

Comment: @ba - using his exact English spelling, the fourth result pointed to Psalms 119. (It would have been the third result, but the second one was this page!)

Comment: @Dave [I only see one result](https://www.google.com/search?q=Lulei+Sorascha+Az+Avadeti+MeOni): this page.

Comment: @Dave, not for me!

Comment: @msh210 better?

Comment: @SethJ, better, or, perhaps more likely, your recent edit to the question shows I was wrong to start with in saying it's a "guessing-game" question. Or, most likely of all, I really don't get what the criteria are of the sort of "guessing-game" questions that that blog post says are no good.

Comment: @msh210 - try [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Lulei+Sorascha+Az+Avadeti+MeOni#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=Lulei+Sorascha&oq=Lulei+Sorascha&gs_l=serp.3..0i10i30.9554.9554.1.10017.1.1.0.0.0.0.143.143.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c.zS4R6jdfVpQ&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=9d7eac37a5baeb65&biw=1024&bih=627) (sometimes less is more).

Comment: @Dave I'm seeing this question and references to the song without citation.

Comment: @SethJ Now it got bumped to fifth place (due to an additional mi.yodeya result). *"LULEI SORAS'CHA, a classic nigun by Rabbi Shlomo Carlebach z"l, comes from T'hilim 119, the longest chapter in all of Tanach..."*

Comment: @Dave, where is that hit?

Comment: @SethJ it's the fifth one on the page I linked to 3 comments ago. The excerpt is from ou.org.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The source is [Psalms 119:92](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%98_%D7%A6%D7%91) -

> לוּלֵי תוֹרָתְךָ שַׁעֲשֻׁעָי אָז אָבַדְתִּי בְעָנְיִי

Or, in the [JPS translation](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26b9.htm#92) -

> Unless Thy law had been my delight, I should then have perished in mine affliction.